# Issues with an array in a foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I am building a function which can upload either a single image or multiple images, depending on if it came from an array of fields or not.

Here is the function and the caller:

```
private function imageUpload($image, $altText, $uploadDir)
{

    $uploadDir = (!substr($uploadDir, "/")) ? $uploadDir."/" : $uploadDir;
    print_r($_POST[$image]);
    if(is_array($_POST[$image]))
    {

        foreach($_FILES[$image] as $image)  //Line 316
        {

            //$targetPath = $uploadDir.basename($image['name']);
            //echo $targetPath;
            echo "array";

        }

    }
    else
    {

        $targetPath = $uploadDir.basename($image['name']);
        //echo $targetPath;
        echo "not array";

    }

}

$this->imageUpload('pei_image', 'pei_alt', '/images/upload/products/');
```

I have tried using 1/2 image fields in the pei_image[] fields, but I get the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>   Message: Undefined index: pei_image
>
> Filename: models/products_model.php
>
> Line Number: 316
>
> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
>
> Filename: models/products_model.php
>
> Line Number: 316

But when I print_r'd the $_POST[$image], I got an array with the correct amount of values. Here is the result:

> Array ( [0] => 06 Lect03 WD Concepts - mod SP.png [1] => brtemplate.jpg )

What is wrong?

**Edit**

The $_FILES array is empty, why is this? Here are 2 of the image upload fields in the form:

```
<input type="file" name="pei_image[]" value="Showing-the-Heavy-horse.jpg" class="imageUpload" onchange="removePreviewButton(this, 2);">
<input type="file" name="pei_image[]" value="Showing-the-Heavy-horse.jpg" class="imageUpload" onchange="removePreviewButton(this, 3);">
```

Comment: You're checking if `$_POST[$image]` is an array, and then attempting to loop on `$_FILES[$image]` ...

Comment: You wrote `$_FILES` instead of `$_FILE`

Comment: do print_r($_POST) and print_r($_FILES) and see if they are populated right

Comment: @Florent $_FILES is correct...

Comment: According to the error, `$_FILES['pei_image']` doesn't exist...

Comment: @Florent $_FILE gives an undefined variable wheras $_FILES gives undefined index because $_FILES is a superglobal array.

Comment: @MianKhurramIjaz Your test showed me that$_FILES was empty and a look at my enctype showed me I had a typo in it :S Rookie error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a typo in my enctype, therefore it defaulted to  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" so it would not upload to the $_FILES array.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
foreach($_FILES[$image] as $image)
```

by

```
foreach($_FILES as $image)
```

Comment: But I have 1 image field on the form for the main image and upto 17 for extra images and they need processing differently, how would I make that work?

Comment: $counter = 0;
foreach($_FILES[$image] as $image) {
  if($counter<1) { /* process the first one */; $counter++;}

Comment: Please see the edit above, this might help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
private function imageUpload($image, $altText, $uploadDir)
{

    $uploadDir = (!substr($uploadDir, "/")) ? $uploadDir."/" : $uploadDir;

    if(is_array($image)
    {

        foreach($image as $img)  //Line 316
        {

            //$targetPath = $uploadDir.basename($image['name']);
            //echo $targetPath;
            echo "array";

        }

    }
    else
    {

        $targetPath = $uploadDir.basename($image['name']);
        //echo $targetPath;
        echo "not array";

    }

}

$this->imageUpload('pei_image', 'pei_alt', '/images/upload/products/');
```

Comment: All I'm passing in the first arguement is a string containing the name of the fields, not the actual array.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that $image is the name of your field, e.g. `'pictures'` or `'images'` or whatever, this would be better:

```
if (!empty($_FILES[$image])) {
    foreach ($_FILES[$image]["error"] as $key => $error) {
        if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
            $tmp_name = $_FILES[$image]["tmp_name"][$key];
            $name = $_FILES[$image]["name"][$key];

            // do your stuff
        }
    }
}
```